# Create typings for IIFE

Tags: typescript

I have a generic validation function which I want to use for type/refactoring safe TypeScript validations.

It looks like this

```js
export function v3<T>(
  sut: T,
  validations: Validation<T>[]
): ValidationResult<T> {
  const result: ValidationResult<T> = {}
  validations.forEach((validation) => {
    const propertyValidation = validation()
    propertyValidation.fns.forEach((fn) => /** validation calls here*/)
  })
  return result
}
```

The `Validation<T>` looks like this

```js
export type Validation<T> = () => {
  property: string
  fns: ((value: string) => Result<string, ValidationError>)[]
}
```

This definition is incomplete but it works.

It is incomplete as you can see from the usage of the `v3` function:

```js
const sut: ContactPerson = {
  firstName: 'Jane',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: null
}

v3<ContactPerson>(sut, [
  () =>
    ((property) => ({
      property,
      fns: [
        (value) =>
          !notNullOrUndefined(value)
            ? Ok(value)
            : Err(new ValidationError(`${property} must not be empty`))
      ]
    }))('this needs to be typed')
])
```

The missing piece of type declarations is the IIFE (`((property)....('this needs to be typed')`)

I'm using the `ts-simple-nameof` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-simple-nameof) which allows me to create a string from an object property like this:

```js
(p => p.firstName) // this replaces 'this needs to be typed'
```

The signature is `(obj:T) => string`.

That's where I'm struggling: How can I create a type for the IIFE so I can set the type of `property` to `(obj:T) => string`. As I'm callling the IIFE it seems to be transparent to the compiler.

`ValidationError` extends `Error`:

```js
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  type: string
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message)
    this.type = 'ValidationError'
  }
}
```

`Result` is defined in `ts-results` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-results):

```js
export declare type Result<T, E> = Ok<T> | Err<E>;
export declare const Ok: typeof OkImpl & (<T>(val: T) => Ok<T>);
export declare type Ok<T> = OkImpl<T>;
export declare const Err: typeof ErrImpl & (<E>(err: E) => Err<E>);
export declare type Err<E> = ErrImpl<E>;
```

`ValidationResult` looks like this:

```js
export type ValidationResult<T> =
  | {
      [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
        ? ValidationResult<T[K]>
        : Result<T[K], ValidationError>
    }
  | never
```

The complete TypeScript playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false#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-IkEtUuLj4CnM1Cs0YcmXcqYzOYhwUrNai8U5yVoYhvBCoL3EbQgJjra1QRD2XhfFMp4wUm6NRrZ6wVqsAfQHznAMUVEEZKbLJk3CHwuBglAATFQKTiWTfaxRUAAfOs3tnFSyLgDCey8AWYQXqSMB7lmtSEJqjRiuk1hHJ8HgwC4QRoLEvJtoWrTWCWqZuCqaoagEkbVNwaDGhscADqgHZ3LwqBwLw9yoNwUYbAE1h1KQEq4pcJ6jIGNwiLe94gfgYEaA+ewsoyqAALw0Nx5AUHetbKaJ37DL+nJWAAshejzVFx0GkJQVDOH6Jn+OQijONwKSgckDKoEOqrqjZXjIkOHbCpOcHbL2uIHIuuRjmAkJDth4ZBXmapIvYSAeEweGLiurDucR1SkaxFE4BsfpLGE+DEEq2bKawxBZi4yKZTZ-G6aexjiWQihUqBsBSY+dZyYpCjqaZtlUFpZg6U2Bn4EZNgadQlneTYkxYLOECUEcACiFl4U1XmLctZAbRSsCvBoa21rtc6ragG2FAAvsAHJWH+yzCvyaBFrFUBGFEwATkgvBAos-2ws0rRsMVDEgODUARJArCYDgGlaLoMAGKMHQJGAVppBECmMXsOAjejXQfFouN2I4I0ANrBEkYRZLwFwGhISIwAAujWGjiFwLNkEjsBHHzMBHHkSTDaM56Xteqn3t1qkvl+xJ0KS5JUhCtL0hFtaCyNEsc5oOiwCNLXSxSW7iZJRpgAA1j0LhgLWRYjUJVSiRSxD4Boao2-c9saI7oxIudK0HUdA4nbWa0vPtYsEkiwQa+Cet0jADK3cAJIDhAU5-QDtGkHSINaH7oPg4UGcwFnv3-bEXhJKShdoPJDdg-gvCFA9qBPUK4CvakiUoMDuafaWP1ktXgPYCE6Qt7w5mBFDMOGvDeCDXPhgEnSCBEEgMRxBjVprXpAAKFAAJoaFiM9kNoxDjjHJhE5jKTYxkXjlITe-Ez0Rd40BUAf50J+QUWQjUbM6VAAAJKAvAwKMSIp5TMqAkjEHsKgb2aJkGoIDLoVy1QsRz0DHWfMgROCSGHjKba1Nab00ZqQlm7Naxcy3gOQQ9BGAsHYKQvgAgZByEUKgFQ8h1D62RvfYwgpk6JRZtJXgskdZgErBeK8ptupe1tr7OsI0SRkkpGbNWqQE4vnkYo6sRjRjGzvO1CSnVUAyNkgpGgcsL7pE0oJZgwkVKWPNjYuxPUHG+FXtLAaNlXGx2IEHaOh0XhhyuupK25lQFjXATyVsvdfJdk2PBD6RxuD2CzoLFE9wGpNnkJjEAVs0AbgUVWGsCFlSsAiN4YgGwEhQCwGAAA5FnXULFCGNGJpGS0ZDUABCePg6gC5dJ1mQtOAcUB9RZxyuRI0+VAhuj3iMk4VSTG1Nco8LU4BOxgB4CAWMEBn4IFkOCewQImCLm8FvVwpyGKIFOV5POxVTkmkgoiOu-YfkBIQawf6nBaIBgipOP0Q53oPMWU8ZA0xAIpGIEgJAMxUpTIpN4VcvdrCHOIFuLEuz9wODpMeRqow4SyFKTssxYT44pwiknBOady6VzHrnCRWcsQaHOaSKqmJp7g1QAAMlseZXxFBeo0EvuDcyjIy5K0ztncetd67jJoE3WVrcEnpyVRXFVuc+VoBmpqwVEQ54fn9myw1NdjWAvqFiCgfzWHCFEA6syIsqBmtfGwkQHD8G8LePwwRwjtZ6pKgaquRq-kerAE6v5WBXXsNYBpL1lNWZmvXiYSmFSUj7jzQKigrMWS5qgEkVmQgU1xrIF6gRcaE2kkoGWitNANDhpuoqyN7Kc412OTCQEKA42oGzdpcwi4j5AiVEOHAWcBXWXqNYLARwMKthcvCl42pNmuUtJkwKQ9ingOCG4ZV8YYBooNKwVC3gQxwBADAAu0UKjUTVEwfUJwRYCQJHVTUgFk3+tTavdNmaKQXDA+7eqskNAaWUo2tp5kxGjXHVMydD60AzqmNuhdPFl2pBPRXAAtGei9hp3CeCeOAfAeSPrEICsWRcbATgYjo3uDKKDmArpbHyUMOEtqjB-aMsASR-3urTUJqgGb7xgYuBB+oWAoM1tg+kZ1pIk3UEpmAewdNYCZpGgJhoWAZq4y9TIxwntrbqNrEPYhprWX6qzvoTt91TAAGJUgoPPVACa+AGTyHGAAGXkrJ0gFwUrnAuOJYAoBICwEQEO5eESKDrRoH691TDuEiY4elqQQaFDKFUO2g2KMR0NksDYcmFQyPVGzLEJac4bNW1LLvQBVpiBWz6DkOIgx2RlbKI4ZwVWQy1eWsQyObwojNf3ikI6HWBiJOQ02FJ3HszpJFNNK2vFDjvHoGcS41xbhFNwc8V46JPh4VQACIECAQTUhDDCOECJ3k9LRIgjEuBGtDz4wSbRKtqTq0ZUyEBpWFvJK422Fbz0MlcQ2x9c7cpIzGnqXAjymoQI6gOy4BZrBEemhEBIS0KQbRYDtFwBEKUGPrI9MOb0cg-TgqDIiHw1gxsRijEIVucYExJAxU2NMh3EHZms40J4zOXh1OvW4VyoI2kPbQCOMcE4NgORDKL8CHTWCfa-WeapF49b1h6yDsYzZMJpMh2t6Hm3+yDmp6Occk4JwzjnDz8BF2cAUR15LRcF2JxenlNADY+5EA3zeAKiWV4tfGGgTgV2stnwsnfJ+ebi4lvg4FGb-y73LcjOt-Lu3LTpwKid5Mpstj0rEPXBLHc4E1kHjJRHy2Jirwx5kp+F8CfVJJ6mQBS0wEOrV4Fz4Yb9XYKZ8QgsFCaFd4m5VyzmjAqcC8DgOdsv+naJPGWZRRiNE6I5EYsxNEbFVmcSDpbw9hI3FMA8a7bxMAuot6lf497okzptL2qpZLTt3EuzWl4vvd-ZF+J9Rjb7RqQaCJbrQJ4-6IbOwiTv5XS-7WK362KyzSrNh1YrRwFQEv7oG3gQEfhQGf6X4uyYEIEWySqoGJY3jrSgFoFv5UFXSQF3id7jSGRS7WDgFXQWTvLsGv4XTyDJb2SOQSTOQRRS6r5Qp5zdzm6Z7ZKhRxDhSRTGSz7WbxQoJJSOjF7gIr7wKahLJ5SQrIhFQlRlSD68GGgCoQA1TI5ZRn4jwEgtRtQ37-72J9TyDYF7T8GcHMHgITT7I8E4FJacFzQLRmGXQABiXByuTkSQ661hnkEhq2-kyhfYIUUyYU66xkMhKhkAahyUzuRu2hKOJE6++hBUyIgIwMPS9g4IkuM6-cMuqoDEQ+Wc7gXy-ogYsYohTwocMAX2Jg4kwBERViZB3Up0-iYR7hF0gRER3hRuncpAyMhocAdwII-hb+Ah3BpqdSROkYMANooh2YPR7wn6ukXuwQkMpyQI7ypKEA6uNgbWzgjSJ6dyFKYSykestmwAd0HcXcRyvcRxQ8X0RINq0aNcOcwMY2V8G088rc0MIgS8UYESgsyWJWBuqAAAgtUNDIQCkGNnYSYJvNvJNsTIfCfOfFdC8FfDfHfAAlNiMu1r-ATGjJ-EAjNm-BTMyS1ikKMSNF6CALsNAMSUAluJvEgFbFTDTHTDkLQszAOAwpzHQiwsiSIvzLgqLCNFyg4OSAOL4qdLMVyH8D7rEJGP7jXkHjRKHh7uHlMn8G7g3lWNaRQsSH-M3gAU4onuLFaVLJYrHvLFokrDoqrDSAYgDlrEVsYjUmGcjEbLrmbH-pbOghosAddBfh4m7B7AmZZidFHCmfYReMmaQT4myWMUAXHhSdeAQQHMQO8cEvULzEVohnHAnMygDiNAiFnKKVbC2S5B+K+tOF2HZt2raosPnFnGNryn8gKpCcKmKhSJEsWagcmVQAqhGsqqCb8vXEubjNOTqimT8Wbr3EtKijLh9ECauVGhymCUDKmlbFfNQDCfwIvHDIiaEYEYLKjBvCsESY-AfMfGfNBreXKtSUwIhj+cigyRVrScTGyYgH-FBUArLPqVYFAjAnIKvogpgmgrbEgigu0Tgk8E-veYQq+KuFwvwPXlQlKQzEzNzHKXrEwjzL6m6llmRTwmAD6HlvWkIoVqIhqaOVqdIigUha7lAO7o3jAIuIaVAL7iaZOIHggMHtumHhJa8SYFHlACoi3moj7HStruJZpQAdpXbLpZHgGSrHosGcnAyCZfabrjZRYmJPGeQf4u6YRUwamcQYWUgc5X1G5cuQBaEiYDAeQFAcMT4igf4gWf5bQVMdQdAV-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-ToYJsJl-aHT-eHX-SBtJkAwphEuA3AxplpuRGzNAwPTABAwhsJQAOpVhHbuzMyaiwpajo6ohHZjY0QUhlBJBEZbxJTOB0hJD8ByT4pgpkgVIbD0AoCDQGIOPkLgKXbAgjL4DTL9hgRbyaj6YCNFHVAmKXRrS4xFX3juxSSoFSqgMBEf7A6LjaMXhHbYBJDqiBP6MBCGNo6FJohPBmNvAWN2BWMmm2PeOONrKFQeBik8N0CeOeT2PkU2mAgBPuzBOFPczhOCNgCRNZSuBVjolYD5NICxPxMWY+yJMZk1j+JHwrFoTyoaBrPhAbNy3ep6YjP5iJbGbiNxNNwmaqILPGUaA4jEJ7O00GqObtyubuYzAoDea+YBbyTNGhYXDhaRbj20TXmoAABqew44YTpAlTXdHC0L2axq-2DIRQmpUiOp92DoiLms89xgS0YEVIMuDoBNxgA1fzsaTcHSYLsYTAkLYAlTHSRQd0d0gL9qlLELIS95TcKzfU2aI4YE5ymL4IRQcAcwUkpmr81NTI-iESErRwrL1LNklTy5GaXxUWNqLL4L8r9QiWmqRQH4MdxglMAA0vHa3YnazEoKWoa6ncxaI0sHsWQDK5mYsz8CYCoHKzS4lka5mi68YGk2-l67KxqzS4q6MHdMYB+ILFFsAFyh8BAE0LOLwFeKUg7hkpy8nLWFkJ1k8IpEUAAIQUjJwKTyRNyaa7pvgfjGrz52BFvkt9l3oigdLHhRb2q-EIpHywBpDVCN1Cv3p0hNDXbisJxFBAxxsDsCtFDQyrAAESsquAur7aAADMEqRQS0EALIqRQUbLcmGg7r7LEmrMwAtYu7Wrr5H5khBczRO7QbNk2r0dYbm7mr+cFw1EMAa0yAbgFIMiW7pAqBMdMbvLsA5yx7AQTcOI37YANYowAHFcSQwHYAz7cwz7A4b7SUn7wrqBJQD7NLa+Pe-osAUAE2wrFI6u6QNGyx4QfctxjIBNN0BNW91QzRs7Mbq7Ggrb5I7bD6IH2LJgd9fbY7qAHSAAUnkFAB0huwSCO-2xEBoB0gACKjVicuuTunLtoJuhujCLtkBscQAcedv3irtHCUwutctUA+u2IUjQfnKoEUj6uciWd11mfGDCvANGechuepW4jSqOeci5s9BxsJtJvMD9kihitEvuducqDvahfedufZkwAUhaBohweVMWMAAk+g9nN0oIh4sbuUtAxU5y1g1H3nB74XtHjIxH0AdIjbowrMjIQAA).

Comment: Please provide reproducible example: `ValidationError`,  `ValidationResult`, `Result` are missing

Comment: Please add `Result` type

Comment: Added `Result`, `Ok` and `Err`

Comment: Please add `ErrImpl` and `OkImpl`. Try to paste your code in TS playground and check whether it reproducible or not

Comment: I've posted the TS playground link now.

Comment: I can't figure out from this what your problem is or where you want things changed.  It kind of sort of looks like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w6BbGw) might be what you want, but I can't tell.  If that's not right, or even if it is right, could you work on minimizing the code to only stuff necessary to demonstrate the issue (you made the code example compile, but a [mre] should not have anything extraneous in it to distract attention away from the crux of the issue) and explaining exactly where the problem is? Preferably with code that works when it shouldn't and vice versa.

Comment: @jcalz What I want to achieve is to define `Prop<ContactPerson>` as part of the `Validation` type, not inside the function passed to the `v3` function. I want to constrain the property to be a member of `T` type parameter passed in `v3<T>`. The user of `v3` should not have to set this constraint. `v3` should provide that type safety.

Comment: What do you mean by "define" here?  The type `Prop` is only defined in one place. If you're talking about a type annotation, then can you explain why this matters to you? If the compiler cannot infer some type the way you want it to, type annotations are a reasonable approach. Right now I can't tell the difference between "this doesn't work" and "this works but I don't like doing it this way".  Again, a [mre] which demonstrates a problem (e.g., an error where there shouldn't be) without extraneous code (I sincerely doubt you need `unwrap` and everything in there) would help with communication.